# Как принять смс на номер, используя python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sms

Пытаюсь написать бота для приема СМС на выбранный номер. Как я могу, собственно, СМС получить?

Answer (score 2):

Для приема СМС на реальный номер телефона нужно воспользоваться СМС-шлюзами. Например:

- сервис Twilio: [How to Receive and Reply to SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python)
- сервис Nexmo: [Receive an SMS](https://developer.vonage.com/messaging/sms/code-snippets/receiving-an-sms)

Я работал с двумя этими сервисами, в целом работают хорошо. Есть СДК и примеры на Python.

По аналогии вы можете найти программируемые смс-шлюзы и у других провайдеров.